# Cube Design Question - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cube, dimension

We have about 10-15 dimension tables that reflect different levels of granularity and about 15-20 metrics we want to track. Does it make more sense to build one cube at the most granular level and roll up or drill down, or to have multiple cubes at different levels of granularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build one cube at the most granular level. This will provide you with the most flexibility in reporting.

Certain reports might run too slowly, once it's in production or once you test it with sizeable data. Only then should you consider creating more specific cubes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Out of curiosity, what is the rationale behind this practice?